# How to Take a Screenshot [System App Granted]

Tags: android, screenshot

Application in the manifest:

```
android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS" />
```

Need to get screen and analyse colors and text. How can this be done?

Comment: Did you install this app on your own custom ROM, with the app signed by the same signing key that you used for for that ROM?

Comment: I'd installed signed system apk on in genymotion and test it. But question in getting snapshot))

Comment: Do you have keys for signing on Samsung firmare?

Comment: Samsung has signing keys for Samsung firmware.